# How to solve spoj: SCALES - Balancing the Stone?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Here is the problem: [SPOJ - SCALES](http://www.spoj.com/problems/SCALES/)

I have searched on the web and found some information in [TopCoder](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=621590&start=0&mc=9#1013338) and [AoPS](http://www.data.ww.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c163h89090s1_weighing_scales) but still cannot understand. Please give me some more details about how to solve this problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a dynamic-programming problem.

You can balance the scales by n steps.

In the `i-th` step, you can determine put the mass with weight `2`<sup>`i-1`</sup> to the right side or left or neither left nor right. But you must put another mass with `2`<sup>`i-1`</sup> to the left side if the `i-th` bit of the binary representation of W.

After the i-th step, you only have two conditions to balance the scales in the future: one condition is that the scales is balance now and another condition is that the left side is `2`<sup>`i`</sup> units more than right.

Now we can design a dynamic-programming algorithm.

```
dp[i][0]: means after the i-th step the scales is balanced.

dp[i][1]: means after the i-th step the left side of the scales is 2^i units more than right.

If s[i] == 0
    dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][0] + dp[i-1][1];
    dp[i][1] = dp[i-1][1];
else
    dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][0];
    dp[i][1] = dp[i-1][0] + dp[i-1][1];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally understand the formula! but just wonder how one could derive a dp - formula like that, since it's tricky ?

Comment: Not at all. Sometimes you just need to observe how to decompose the state that can make the state more clear. Like this problem, you can decompose the state by n steps and each step just relate to last step. Thus you can design a dp algorithm.

Comment: I must also suggest you @Tung that this beautiful problem had that hint of taking DP[i][j] where j can be 0 or 1 only! Just by giving the binary representation! :) And you have to solve tons of DP to become a master!